# Adding Navigation controller in DetailViewController ipad

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

Please tell me how i can do this. I am making an iPad app.I have a list in tableview of RootViewController , clicking on each of which displays a table having information in DetailViewController. By default there is a tab bar at the top of the DetailViewController but i want to add navigation controller over there.

Answer (score 0):

Just push a new controller in your current navigation controller! No need for a new one.